# Introduce Generic/Dynamic Interface with PostSharp

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I recently found [this question](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/questions/881-introduce-generic-interface) on PostSharp's support forum.  It doesn't look like this question was asked here, so I will do that now.

The original question inquired about generic interfaces.  I am interested in doing that, but I am also interested in simply implementing an interface dynamically on an object, while pointing to a proxy implementation.

Here is what I am attempting to accomplish, but as you can see, I am getting an error on the marked line below, as `IntroduceInterfaceAttribute` is not an `IAspect`.

```
public class ApplyInterfaces : TypeLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    readonly Type[] interfaceTypes;
    public ApplyInterfaces( params Type[] interfaceTypes )
    {
        this.interfaceTypes = interfaceTypes;
    }

    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects( object targetElement )
    {
        var type = (Type)targetElement;
        var targetTypes = InterfaceTypeProvider.GetInterfacesFor( type ); // pseudo-code.  Get interfaces to implement "somewhere".

        foreach ( var interfaceType in interfaceTypes.Concat( targetTypes ) )
        {
            yield return new AspectInstance( type, new IntroduceInterfaceAttribute( interfaceType ) ); // doesn't work.
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible with PostSharp?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve. Something with generics or something with implementing an interface is rather broad. Please show an example of what you are trying to do and what you tried

Comment: for axample is this what you are trying to do?http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/PostSharp-Principals-Day-14-e28093-Introducing-members-and-interfaces-Part-1 (first link in google)

Comment: You are correct @Batavia, thank you for your feedback.  I could have put more effort into the question.  I have updated with some code and more context.  I have also answered my question below with what I am currently using to work around the generic interface problem, using (what I believe is) the adapter pattern.  Any feedback around either of these would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I am currently solving this problem, but I am definitely open to feedback on if there is a better way.  Also, I would like to verify that this is indeed using [the adapter pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/adapter-design-pattern) as well.

```
[IntroduceInterface( typeof(IGenericInterface) )]
public class DynamicInterfaceAspect : InstanceLevelAspect, IGenericInterface
{
    readonly Type parameterType;

    public DynamicInterfaceAspect( Type parameterType )
    {
        this.parameterType = parameterType;
    }

    public override void RuntimeInitializeInstance()
    {
        var type = typeof(GenericInterfaceAdapter<>).MakeGenericType( parameterType );
        Inner = (IGenericInterface)Activator.CreateInstance( type, Instance );
    }

    IGenericInterface Inner { get; set; }
    public void HelloWorld( object parameter ) => Inner.HelloWorld( parameter );
}

public interface IGenericInterface
{
    void HelloWorld( object parameter );
}

public class GenericInterfaceAdapter<T> : IGenericInterface
{
    readonly IGenericInterface<T> inner;

    public GenericInterfaceAdapter( IGenericInterface<T> inner )
    {
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public void HelloWorld( object parameter ) => inner.HelloWorld( (T)parameter );
}

public interface IGenericInterface<in T>
{
    void HelloWorld( T parameter );
}
```

Comment: Since you want to provide a proxy implementation, you may also be interested in trying out [CompositionAspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_compositionaspect). Note, that [IntroduceInterface] is still a recommended way for introducing interfaces.